# How to make a flash in button [ Tkinter library]

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have 2 buttons
When I click one of them I would like the other to flash for 10 seconds
Why isn't it working for me?
tnx:)

```
def test (self):
    if self.my_button1.cget("bg") == "yellowgreen":
         t_end = time.time() + 10 * 1
         while time.time() < t_end:
         # This line doesn't work for me
            self.my_button12.configure(bg="red")
            time.sleep(1)
            self.my_button12.configure(bg="silver")
            time.sleep(1)
         pass
```

The button should flash for 10 seconds

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using `sleep` in tkinter applications, as the main GUI event loop will hang during sleep and your app will be unresponsive during that time. Instead, you should use the built in `after` method to call a function after a certain amount of time.

Also, since you've used `self` here, I assume `test` is a method in some other class - you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76893522/edit) your question to include the relevant code for that class, as it may be helpful to others. Lastly, there are some indentation errors here, so you may want to fix those!

Anyway...here goes

```
# declare a variable in the instance scope (i.e., in the __init__ method)
# to store the total blink count
self.blink_count = 0
```

```
# define a method to blink the button
def blink(self):
    self.blink_count += 1  # increment the counter
    if self.blink_count <= 10:
        if self.my_button12.cget("bg") != "red":
            self.my_button12.configure(bg="red")  # set the new background color
        else:
            self.my_button12.configure(bg="#D9D9D9")
        self.after(1000, self.blink)  # call the blink function again to repeat
    else:
        self.my_button12.configure(bg="yellowgreen")  # restore the default bg color
        self.blink_count = 0  # reset the counter
```

This is a fairly naïve approach, as the use of a counter only allows you to blink one button at a time (or, more accurately, all blinking buttons will stop whenever the *first* button you blinked stops, i.e., `blink_count` reaches 10) but it should give you a place to start.